# Microsoft translator azure are returning null with PHP API

Tags: php, azure, microsoft-translator

The output is null, PHP version is 5.6. I added the line to the PHP.INI file.
I have tried with the HTTP and HTTP's but it still shows the null. I updated the host address to include the API call URL as shown in the azure control panel. And there is not much information about people receiving this error.

```
<?php

// NOTE: Be sure to uncomment the following line in your php.ini file.
// ;extension=php_openssl.dll

// **********************************************
// *** Update or verify the following values. ***
// **********************************************

// Replace the subscriptionKey string value with your valid subscription key.
$key = 'KEY_REMOVED';

$host = "https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken";
$path = "/translate?api-version=3.0";

// Translate to German and Italian.
$params = "&to=de&to=it";

$text = "Hello, world!";

if (!function_exists('com_create_guid')) {
  function com_create_guid() {
    return sprintf( '%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
        mt_rand( 0, 0x0fff ) | 0x4000,
        mt_rand( 0, 0x3fff ) | 0x8000,
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff )
    );
  }
}

function Translate ($host, $path, $key, $params, $content) {

    $headers = "Content-type: application/json\r\n" .
        "Content-length: " . strlen($content) . "\r\n" .
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $key\r\n" .
        "X-ClientTraceId: " . com_create_guid() . "\r\n";

    // NOTE: Use the key 'http' even if you are making an HTTPS request. See:
    // http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php
    $options = array (
        'http' => array (
            'header' => $headers,
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => $content
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create ($options);
    $result = file_get_contents ($host . $path . $params, false, $context);
    return $result;
}

$requestBody = array (
    array (
        'Text' => $text,
    ),
);
$content = json_encode($requestBody);

$result = Translate ($host, $path, $key, $params, $content);

// Note: We convert result, which is JSON, to and from an object so we can pretty-print it.
// We want to avoid escaping any Unicode characters that result contains. See:
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
$json = json_encode(json_decode($result), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I known, your code is copied from the offical document [`Quickstart: Translate text with the Translator Text REST API (PHP)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstart-php-translate).

According to the section [`Base URLs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference#base-urls) of the reference `Translator Text API v3.0`, the `$host` value should be the one of the list below.

[image]

So you can use `$host = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com";` in your code without any changes. It is the first issue.

Second, the [`Authentication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference#authentication) header is depended on your API type of your Cognitive Services subscription.

1. If your API type is `Translator Text` as the figure below, you will not change any `$headers` code in the function `Translate` of the origin code which value is depended on your location, such as `southeastasia`.

[image]

2. If your API type is `All Cognitive Services` as the figure below, you need to add a header `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region` in the `$headers` code.

[image]

```
$headers = "Content-type: application/json\r\n" .
        "Content-length: " . strlen($content) . "\r\n" .
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $key\r\n" .
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region: southeastasia\r\n" .
        "X-ClientTraceId: " . com_create_guid() . "\r\n";
```

***Note***: there is an issue in the document as below.
[image]

Then, in my environment, PHP version is `7.2.12`, and I run `php -f test.php` which works fine and return the json response for the two different cases above, as below.

[image]

```
[
    {
        "detectedLanguage": {
            "language": "en",
            "score": 1
        },
        "translations": [
            {
                "text": "Hallo Welt!",
                "to": "de"
            },
            {
                "text": "Salve, mondo!",
                "to": "it"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```