# Bing Web Search API v7 doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, css, azure, api, bing

I have copied the JavaScript code onto a JavaScript file and followed the folder format and it doesn't seem to work. I've added my subscription key and I've changed the endpoint like it states. All i want is for someone to search for something via a bar and click a button and it displays the results. Would you know how to do this properly. I've tried nearly everything.

I'm trying to do the .PHP version

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/quickstarts/php

Comment: Also would anyone know how i would implement this                               
             <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <body>
  <form name="bing" onsubmit="return bingWebSearch(this.query.value,
    bingSearchOptions(this), getSubscriptionKey())">
 </body>
</html> into a button and search bar?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to follow the offical tutorial [`Quickstart: Use PHP to call the Bing Web Search API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/quickstarts/php) to copy code and run with my key. It did not work as yours and got the result as the figure below.

[image]

Then, I was aware of your issue which may be as same as the other SO thread [Microsoft translator azure are returning null with PHP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54434137/microsoft-translator-azure-are-returning-null-with-php-api/54458421#54458421).

On Azure, there are two API types of Cognitive Service for Bing Web Search include `All Cognitive Services` (All-in-one subscription) and `Bing Search v7` (Only Bing Search), as the figures below.

Fig 1. API type `All Cognitive Services` (All-in-one subscription) which endpoint is depended on your service region (`Location`)

[image]

Fig 2. API type `Bing Search v7` (Only Bing Search)

[image]

They are using different endpoints, for example, in my `All Cognitive Service` of Location `Southeast Asia`, the endpoint is `https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/`. And for Bing Search v7 in this API type, the final endpoint must have to be changed with `https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search`.

So the offical code for PHP just need to be changed two code lines, as below, after I test success.

1. For using API type `All Cognitive Services`, the code is:

   ```
   $accessKey = '<your key for API type of All Cognitive Services>';
   $endpoint ='https://<the region of your cognitive service like southeastasia>.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search';
   ```
2. For using API type `Bing Search v7`, the code is:

   ```
   $accessKey = '<your key for API type of Bing Search v7>';
   $endpoint = 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search';
   ```

---

For your second question in your comment, the simple solution for HTML web page and php script is as below.

**searchbar.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form name="bing" method="POST" action="search.php">
        <input type="text" name="term">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**search.php**: just need to change the offical code for `$term`.

```
<?php
// as above
$accessKey = '<the key of your Cognitive Services>';
$endpoint = '<the endpoint of your Cognitive Services>';

// The `term` index is mapping to the `name` value of type `text` of tag `input` name `term`. 
// Case when use `method="POST"` in form tag, the value of `term` got by `$_POST` method
// Or case when use `GET` method, it change to `$_GET`.
$term = $_POST['term']; 

function BingWebSearch ($url, $key, $query) {
    /* Prepare the HTTP request.
     * NOTE: Use the key 'http' even if you are making an HTTPS request.
     * See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php.
     */
    $headers = "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $key\r\n";
    $options = array ('http' => array (
                          'header' => $headers,
                           'method' => 'GET'));

    // Perform the request and get a JSON response.
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url . "?q=" . urlencode($query), false, $context);
    echo $result;
    // Extract Bing HTTP headers.
    $headers = array();
    foreach ($http_response_header as $k => $v) {
        $h = explode(":", $v, 2);
        if (isset($h[1]))
            if (preg_match("/^BingAPIs-/", $h[0]) || preg_match("/^X-MSEdge-/", $h[0]))
                $headers[trim($h[0])] = trim($h[1]);
    }

    return array($headers, $result);
}

// Validates the subscription key.
if (strlen($accessKey) == 32) {

    print "Searching the Web for: " . $term . "\n";
    // Makes the request.
    list($headers, $json) = BingWebSearch($endpoint, $accessKey, $term);

    print "\nRelevant Headers:\n\n";
    foreach ($headers as $k => $v) {
        print $k . ": " . $v . "\n";
    }
    // Prints JSON encoded response.
    print "\nJSON Response:\n\n";
    echo $json;
    echo json_encode(json_decode($json), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

} else {

    print("Invalid Bing Search API subscription key!\n");
    print("Please paste yours into the source code.\n");

}
?>
```

Comment: So what would the search.php look like as complete?

Comment: @UKzRomulus I update my `search.php` code as complete.